# How to migrate data from Netezza to Bigquery

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-migration, netezza

Can someone please share some links/references or guide me how to do database migration from IBM Netezza to Google's Bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the [data warehouse migration offer](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/migrating-your-traditional-data-warehouse-platform-to-bigquery-announcing-the-data-warehouse-migration-offer) due to this process involves lots of  steps such as:

- Migration Strategy
- Migration Plan
- Effort estimation
- Technical Architecture

Additional, GCP does not offer official documentation to  migrate from Netezza to BigQuery; nevertheless, you can take a look into the [Data Transfer Service migration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/migrations) documentation to get an idea of all the work that this migration implies.

On the other hand, I found some  [third-party](https://datavirtuality.com/connectors/integrate/ibm-netezza/google-bigquery/) companies that offers this service, maybe  you can take a look there, and finally a [Medium post](https://medium.com/petabytz/data-migration-to-gcp-netezaa-migration-to-gcp-bigquery-5fb79b39f13c) that talks about this.